# Closed-form of $\int_0^{\pi/4} \sin(\sin(x)) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Let $I(b)$ is the following integral

$$I(b)=\int_0^b \sin(\sin(x)) \, dx.$$

There are some $b$ value for that we know a closed-form of $I(b)$ in term of [Struve function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) $\mathbf{H}_n(x)$. For example

$$\begin{align}
I(\pi/2) = & \, \frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{H}_0(1) \\
I(\pi) = & \, \pi\mathbf{H}_0(1) \\
I(3\pi/2) = & \, \frac{\pi}{2}\mathbf{H}_0(1) \\
I(2\pi) = & \, 0.
\end{align}$$

I know that the closed-form of $I(k\pi/2)$ comes from the [integral form of Struve function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function#Integral_form), but perhaps there are other closed forms of this type of integrals.

**Question.** Is there a closed-form of $I(\pi/4)=\int_0^{\pi/4} \sin(\sin(x)) \, dx$?

Comment: No, there aren't known to be any. Unless, of course, you are willing to accept “incomplete” Struve functions as closed forms.

Comment: Conjecture for $I(\pi/4)$ Integral $$I(\pi/4)=\frac{\pi  \pmb{H}_0(1)}{2} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1} \sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^k \binom{-1/2}{k}}{((2 n-1)\text{!!})^2}$$

Comment: +1 @JamesArathoon I think that is correct ... Need time to think.

Comment: Searching “Kampe de Feriet” function may give a closed form

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^b\sin(\sin x)~dx$

$=\int_0^b\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=-\int_0^b\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n\sin^{2n}x}{(2n+1)!}d(\cos x)$

$=\int_0^b\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}(1-\cos^2x)^n}{(2n+1)!}d(\cos x)$

$=\int_0^b\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}C_k^n(-1)^k\cos^{2k}x}{(2n+1)!}d(\cos x)$

$=\int_0^b\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k+1}n!\cos^{2k}x}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}d(\cos x)$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k+1}n!\cos^{2k+1}x}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}\right]_0^b$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n+k+1}n!(\cos^{2k+1}b-1)}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2k+1)}$