# Closed-form of the sequence ${_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac12,-n\\\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|\,\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

Is there a closed-form of the following sequence?

$$a_n={_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac12,-n\\\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|\,\frac{1}{2}\right),$$

where $_2F_1$ is the [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. *Maple* could evaluate $a_n$ for arbitrary $n$. The exact values for $a_n$ from $n=0$ to $10$. 
$$1,\frac 56,{\frac {43}{60}},{\frac {177}{280}},{\frac {2867}{5040}},{
\frac {11531}{22176}},{\frac {92479}{192192}},{\frac {74069}{164736}},
{\frac {2371495}{5601024}},{\frac {9488411}{23648768}},{\frac {
126527543}{331082752}},\dots$$

It is interesting, that the first $7$ term of the numerator sequence matches with [$\text{A126963}$](http://oeis.org/A126963) on OEIS, but after that it breaks.

Comment: One can extend your extend your observation about the numerators. Kindly see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645203/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\tag{1}a_n:={_2F_1}\left(\begin{array}c\tfrac12\quad -n\\\tfrac32\end{array}\middle|\,\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
is defined as :
(with $(q)_j=q\,(q+1)\cdots(q+j-1)$ for $\,j>0\;$ the rising [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) ) :
\begin{align}
a_n&=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac 12\right)_j\;(-n)_j}{\left(\frac 32\right)_j\;j!\,2^j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{\frac 12\;(-n)_j}{\left(j+\frac 12\right)\;j!\,2^j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{\left(2j+1\right)\;(n-j)!\;j!}\left(-\frac 12\right)^j\\
&=f_n\left(-\frac 12\right)\\
\end{align}
with $\;\displaystyle f_n(x):=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\frac{x^j}{2j+1}$

Since $\;\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}(t^2)^j=\left(1+t^2\right)^n\;$ and $\;\displaystyle\int t^{2j}\;dt=\frac{t^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\;$ we deduce that 
$$t\,f_n(t^2)=\int (1+t^2)^n\; dx$$
and (since $(i/\sqrt{2})^2=-1/2$) that 
$$\tag{2}a_n=-i\sqrt{2}\int_0^{i/\sqrt{2}}(1+x^2)^n\;dx$$
or simply that
$$\tag{3}a_n=\int_0^1\left(1-\frac {t^2}2\right)^n\;dt$$
Of course we could have found this directly using the appropriate integral for the hypergeometric series... Anyway such integral formulations may return clearer expressions for $\;\displaystyle\sum \frac {a_n}{n!}\;$ and so on.

Comment: I've got very similiar expression using an [Euler's integral transormation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Euler.27s_integral_transform). After this two answers as I see there is no hope to get a closed-form of $a_n$ without using integral or summation. Thank you for your answer. By the way the indefinite version of your result gives $t$ times a hypergeom function at $t^2/2$ instead of $1/2$. As we can see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%281-t%5E2%2F2%29%5En%2Ct%5D). +1.

Comment: @user153012: As explained by Lucian in the comments we may rewrite it as an [incomplete beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) (with the substitution $t:=\sqrt{2}\sin(x)$) getting : $$a_n=\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(x)^{2n+1}\;dx=\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}B\left(\frac 12,\frac 12, n+1\right)$$ as you may try in [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Beta%5B1%2F2%2C1%2F2%2C3%2B1%5D%2FSqrt%5B2%5D) (which doesn't seem to help...)

Answer (score 2):

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$ `Hello, there! Cleo just asked me to post this:`

Starting at $n=0$, we have $F(n)=\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{2^n~(2n+1)!!},$ where $a_{k>0}$ form the sequence described [here](http://oeis.org/A090470).

Comment: Sadly using your $a_n$ your answer just shows a connection between ${_2F_1}(1/2,1/2+n;3/2;-1)$ and my $a_n$. Thank you anyway. I guess the @Cleo thing was just a joke because of this answer style. +1.

Comment: @user153012: So basically you've been trying to find a general formula for integrals of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi4\cos^{2n+1}(x)~dx$ ?

Comment: The problem appeared while I tried to get a closed-form of the series in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/979161/153012).

Comment: @user153012: As I already explained, a closed form for the definite integral in your other post only exists if we are willing to accept the existence of incomplete Struve functions.

Comment: Yes I've read that, but if we have a cloed-form of this hypergeom function, then at least we'll have a series for that integral without double summation.

Comment: @user153012: You can use $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi4\sin^{2n+1}(x)~dx = \dfrac12~B\bigg(\dfrac12~,~n+1~,~\dfrac12\bigg)$ right after the second row of Harry's answer.