# On a "coincidence" of two sequences involving $a_n = {_2F_1}\left(\tfrac{1}{2},-n;\tfrac{3}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

This was inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979197/). Define,

$$a_n = {_2F_1}\left(\tfrac{1}{2},-n;\tfrac{3}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}\right)$$

$$b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{-\tfrac{1}{2}}{k}\big(-\tfrac{1}{2}\big)^k$$

where $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function and binomial $\binom n k$. The first few ***numerators*** $N$ are,

$$N_1(n) = \color{brown}{1, \,5, \,43, \,177, \,2867, \,11531, 92479}, \,74069, 2371495,\dots$$

$$N_2(n) = \color{brown}{1, \,5, \,43, \,177, \,2867, \,11531, 92479}, \,370345, 11857475,\dots$$

respectively, and where the latter is sequence [A126963](http://oeis.org/A126963). As the OP from the other post pointed out, the first seven numerators match.

I thought it was a peculiar coincidence so, after some tinkering, found a possible relationship.

> **Q:** How do we show that,
>   $$(2n+1)!!\, a_n = (2n)!!\, b_n$$
>   or equivalently,
>   $${_2F_1}\left(\tfrac{1}{2},-n;\tfrac{3}{2};\tfrac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}\,  \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{-\tfrac{1}{2}}{k}\big(-\tfrac{1}{2}\big)^k$$

Comment: so $b_n$ is the truncated power series for $i (1-x)^{1/2}$ at $x = -1/2$ ? and isn't $_2F_1(\ldots)$ able to truncate power series ?

Comment: @user1952009: Well, I just found this relationship empirically, so maybe someone can establish it more rigorously.

Comment: Do you have a background about special functions?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: Only for some special functions.  :)

Comment: You have a hypergeometric function and you need to know some thing about it!